# I wrote a garbage collector for my language but it has a problem

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection

I'm writing an interpreted language in Haskell. The evaluator I wrote runs on a State monad which stores a map from strings (variable names) to ints (memory addresses), which stores the "memory address" of each variable. The state also stores a map from ints to `Value`s, which keeps track of which value is stored at which address.

Here is a simplified version of the types for the AST:

```hs
data Value = IntV Int | CharV Char | RefV Int | ListV [Int]
data Expr = ForEach String Value [Expr] | VarDef String Value
type Program = [Expr]
```

So we have two primitive values: ints and chars.
Also, there are references, which contain the address of a value. This allows me to pass values by reference when a function requires it. Finally, there are lists, which contain the addresses of its values. This makes lists mutable, allowing me to pass elements of a list by reference.

I added a garbage collector to the monad stack of the evaluator. Every now and then, the garbage collector runs and finds all the "memory addresses" that are reachable from any variable definition (the `Value` of each variable is stored at an address, which can in turn contain references to other addresses, and so on). Any address that is considered unreachable by this process is removed from the map in the State, freeing up some memory.

In this language, you can say `let x="abc"`. Strings are lists of chars, so when the evaluator sees this it stores each char in a memory address. So, for example, the state may end up like this:

```hs
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM -- A map that always has Ints as keys
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

memoryMap = IM.fromList [(0, CharV 'a'), (1, CharV 'b'), (2, CharV 'c')]
varsMap = M.fromList []
state = (memoryMap, varsMap)
```

Now lets say I have a `ForEach` expression like this one:

```
foreach c in "abc": 
    print c;
```

Here, the evaluator sees a string literal and transforms it into a list value just as I explained above. Then, it binds the name `c` to the first address in that list, and runs the expressions inside the loop. This goes on for each element in the list.

And here is the problem: what happens if the garbage collector runs in the middle of the loop? It won't find any variable from which you can reach the addresses in the list (except for the element currently bound to `c`), and those addresses will be freed. Now, on the next iteration of the loop, `c` will end up bound to an invalid address.

How can I make these addresses visible to the garbage collector? I thought about storing the whole list at some address bound to a hidden variable (something like `_c`). That way, the garbage collector would be able to see those as addresses and wouldn't free them. Although it works for these kind of loops, it doesn't work for other constructions in my language which have similar problems.

I also thought about adding a set of ints to the state, which would keep track of addresses that are not reachable from variables but that the evaluator sets manually as visible. However, this doesn't seem very clean, and maybe there is something better that someone else already thought about.

Or maybe I'm doing something wrong from the start and the way I'm handling string literals is incorrect.

Comment: You need to decouple your notion of GC roots from your notion of variable names. As a second example where your proposed method doesn't work well, but in the other direction ("all variables" means too many roots instead of too few): `foreach c in d: print c; foreach c in "abc": print c;`. In the second loop, the GC should be allowed to collect whatever `d` points to, even though there's a variable pointing at it.

Comment: Normally you'd differentiate between code and memory. Currently, the code is written as if every `Value` in a Program is a captured value. In that case you'd basically need to treat the `Program` as a GC root, or at least the reachable `Expr`s.

Comment: @DanielWagner in your example, the problem is that even though `d` is a variable, it is not used anymore so its value should be collectable? If that is the case, my evaluator is not smart enough yet. Is there any simple way to go about calculating the lifetime of a variable?
Also, what does decoupling GC roots from variable names mean? Should I keep track of addresses that act as roots instead of using the variables saves in the state?

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm sorry but I'm not sure what captured value means. Are those the values that are in scope or something like that? If that is the case, I think I understand what you mean, because the garbage collector is acting as if every value being used is captured in a variable, but that's not true in my example.

Comment: Or maybe the problem is that I initialize strings as lists of addresses, when instead I should take one char out of it on each iteration, and store it at the address of the iterator

Comment: Captured as in kept alive in a closure, e.g. Java `final String foo = "abc"; () -> { return foo; }` vs `() -> { return "abc" };`. In the former, as long as the closure is alive, it will keep alive a reference to a String object in memory. In the latter, there is no String object in memory until the function is invoked, at which point one is created using string data from the bytecode. If your `Expr` can only store its value as a `ListV [Int]` pointing to positions in memory, then your GC would have to keep those positions alive whether or not the Expr is currently executing

Comment: Oh I see. Would that be fixed if instead of having `ListV [Int]` i had `ListV [Value]`? That way I would be able to make the distintion between string literals in the code (a `ListV` containing `CharV`s) and lists initialized in memory (a `ListV` containing `RefV`s, each pointing to the address of a value)

Comment: @thatotherguy actually, a declaration of the form `final String foo = "abc";` creates a compile-time constant, so `return foo;` is exactly the same as `return "abc";`. To avoid this, you’d have to either, remove the `final` modifier, split into declaration and assignment, `final String foo; foo = "abc";` or change the expression to non-constant, like `final String foo = "abc".toString();`. Then, `() -> foo` would have to capture the current value.

Comment: @Holger `javap` confirms. Neat, TIL.

Comment: I'm sorry for reviving this, but I'm trying what @DanielWagner said about decoupling the notion of variables from the notion of GC-roots. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can store the GC-roots? Should my state have something like a Set of ints? Then I would be able to add the addresses of variables to that set, but also the address of the elements in a string like in my example.